# How to go to another tab in the current page after some onClick Action

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some 2 tabs in the current page of the React App , I by default land on on one of the tabs , after completing some action in one tab how to another tab that lies in the same page without the user manually clicking on the required tab.

ReactRouter and Redirect ,also Link just goes to another tab or stays in same page and rerenders on same page . I don't want a rerender on the complete page, just want to go to that component within the same page and render that again that lies under a Tab

Inside Tab1  ----
react component......

handleClick() {

```
 //Goto Tab2

}
```

} key="button" style = {{border: '1px solid black'}} />

Just want to navigate to the tab2  onClick(inside tab1) that exists on the same page without the whole page rerendering or going to another page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735580/how-to-do-a-redirect-to-another-route-with-react-router#40380010