# React-Router v5 not redirecting if accessing specific route using history.push

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-functional-component

In my react app I have `/lead-manager` route, `/login` route
and there is `/` route, latter which is the `app.js` itself that I don't want anyone to access, if someone just goes to the `/` route I wanted them to redirect to `/lead-manager` route. 
So this is what I did according to the solution given 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735580/how-to-do-a-redirect-to-another-route-with-react-router).

My app.jsx part

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Switch,
  useHistory,
  Route,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";

const App = ({ confirmAuthentication }) => {
  let location = useLocation();
  let history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchIt() {
      if (localStorage.jwt !== undefined) {
        confirmAuthentication();
      }
    }
    fetchIt();
    if (location.pathname === "/") {
      history.push("lead-manager");
    }
  }, []);
 return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/testing">
          <TestingComponent />
        </Route>
        <PrivateRoute path="/lead-manager" component={LeadApp} />
        <Route exact path="/login">
          <LoginView />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The output I'm getting when I'm accessing `/` path is `/lead-manager` in the URL. Which is the desired one, but the component doesn't render accordingly with components defined in `/lead-manager` route. It just stays on `/` route even though URL shows `/lead-manager`

Hope this is clear

Comment: How have you defined used Router and is it rendered inside App component?

Comment: I have updated my query now @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: any errors in ur console ?

Comment: @Panther no errors in console

Comment: i think you have to push `/lead-manager` instead of `lead-manager` !!

Comment: @panther i tried that too, but same result

Comment: can you show how is `App` rendered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use history correctly you need to have a Router wrapping  App component up in the hierarchy. Since you are rendering Router within App component, it isn't able to listen to the history changes since the history provided by useHistory doesn't refer to the history used by Router unless App component is wrapped by Router.

Do not render Router inside of App component

Also you have rendered Router as the Switch component inside App component, you must instead import the exact Switch component from `react-router-dom`

Check updated code below

```
import {


    BrowserRouter as Router,
      Switch
      useHistory,
      Route,
      useLocation,
    } from "react-router-dom";

    const App = ({ confirmAuthentication }) => {
      let location = useLocation();
      let history = useHistory();

      useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchIt() {
          if (localStorage.jwt !== undefined) {
            confirmAuthentication();
          }
        }
        fetchIt();
        if (location.pathname === "/") {
          history.push("lead-manager");
        }
      }, []);
     return (
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/testing">
              <TestingComponent />
            </Route>
            <PrivateRoute path="/lead-manager" component={LeadApp} />
            <Route exact path="/login">
              <LoginView />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default (props) => <Router><App {...props}/></Router>
```

Comment: @Subham Khatri. Thanks a lot that works. Thanks for the clear explanation R+