# I want to render the starting page based on user logged in or not on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

What I want is to show the Homepage only if user has previously logged in and didn't logged out. But is user logged out previously then show loginpage. I'm saving auth status to local storage like this: key:auth, value:true/false. Depending on auth value I want to render the starting page.

This is my App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Signup from "./Components/Signup";
import Login from "./Components/Login";
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./Components/HomePage";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const authStatus=localStorage.getItem('auth')

  const setAuth = (value) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(value);
    //alert(value);
  };
  useEffect(()=>{
    setIsAuthenticated(authStatus)
  },[])
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage  />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Its always opening Homepage in the starting but I want Homepage if user login status is true which is saved on localStorage of the browser and Login page if login status is false.

This is my login.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const initialValues = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

export default function Login({setAuth}) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
  function validateForm() {
    return values.email.length > 0 && values.password.length > 0;
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Login();

    
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  function Login() {
    let retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("registeredUsers");
    let users = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
    let Found = users.find(function (user, index) {
      if (user.email === values.email && user.password === values.password) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    if (Found) {
      
      setAuth(true)
      let auth = true;
      localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(auth));
      //navigate("/");
    } else {
      alert("Error email/password");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="LoginContainer">
      <div style={{ display: "flex", width: "100%" }}>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="email">
            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              autoFocus
              type="email"
              name="email"
              value={values.email}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="password">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={values.password}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button
            style={{ marginTop: 10, width: 400 }}
            block
            size="lg"
            type="submit"
            // disabled={!validateForm()}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
      <text style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        Don't have an account? <Link to="/signup">Register</Link>
      </text>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issues

1. Your initial `isAuthenticated` state matches your unauthenticated state.
2. The render doesn't handle any conditional rendering of the homepage or redirecting to your login page.
3. The `Login` component isn't passed the `setAuth` callback.

## Solution

Initialize the `isAuthenticated` from localStorage, use the `useEffect` hook with dependency on `isAuthenticated` to persist authentication state changes to localStorage.

```
function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(
    () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth')) || false
  );

  const setAuth = (value) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(value);
    //alert(value);
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(isAuthenticated));
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={isAuthenticated
            ? <HomePage  />
            : <Navigate to="/login" replace />
          }
        />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login setAuth={setAuth} />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

Login

Update the login function to only call the `setAuth` callback and then imperatively navigate to the homepage.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  login();
};

...

function login() {
  const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("registeredUsers")) || [];
  const found = users.some(user => user.email === values.email && user.password === values.password);

  if (found) {
    setAuth(found);
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  } else {
    alert("Error email/password");
  }
}
```

Comment: @TanjilPranto Welcome, glad to help! Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your getting your `auth` info from local storage but not actually using it anywhere. You should be able to do a conditional route based on if the user is authenticated or not. Something like this.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={ isAuthenticated ? <HomePage  /> : <Login />} />
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
</Routes>
```

Or you could also use a redirect when you are running your `setAuth` method. If the current path is `/` and they dont have the `auth` coookie then redirect them to `/login`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735580/how-to-do-a-redirect-to-another-route-with-react-router) explains a few different ways to achieve the redirect if you chose that way.

Comment: well the problem is gone for now. I'm facing another one. When I'm going to Signup page and returning back to login page and trying to log in I can't update the state then. But If I don't go to the signup page and try to log in its working

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for another way of solving this with React Router 6:

First import the following from react-router-dom

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Then on your return function:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route index path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
    <Route path="/register" element={isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <Register />}></Route>
    <Route path="/login" element={isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <Login />}></Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```