# React function - change url when page loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to React.js and I am not sure how to handle this.

I did a selection with react where the selected option is passed by the link. I am also using the react router.

If no option is selected I want to redirect to the first option when the page loads.

```js
function initTrainer() {

    for(let i = 0; i < trainer.length; i++) {
        trainer[i].link = "/trainer/" + trainer[i].firstName.toLowerCase() + "-" + trainer[i].lastName.toLowerCase();
        trainer[i].key = i;
    }

    if(window.location.pathname === "/") {
        // navigate("/trainer/")
    }
}
```

How can I redirect without a click in a normal function? Is there an easier solution to this problem?

Y
I am using React Router V6 but I want to call navigate() conditionally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a redirect to another route with react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735580/how-to-do-a-redirect-to-another-route-with-react-router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your component to make it work:

```js
const navigate = useState();

return (
  {() => navigate("/your-path")}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you using react-router, you can use `<Redirect>`.. you can read about react-router Redirect here: [React-Router-Redirect](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

Answer (score 1):

When looking at your question, I think you are asking how navigate pragmatically in react.
This can be done using react router. But depending on the react router version this is different.

**In React Router v4**
when you importing  `import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'` your componet getting History object via props.so that you can nvigate,

```
this.props.history.push('/yourpath')
```

**In  React Router V5**

You have to import below import statement where you are using the this pragmatically navigation.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function home() {
  const history = useHistory();

//use this function to navigate
  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/yourpath");
  }


  return (
    <div>home</div>
  )
}
```

**In  In React Router V6**

```
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function home() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  //you can extrat route paramters using useParams hook
  const { id } = useParams();

//use this function to navigate
  function handleClick() {
    navigate("/yourpath");
  }


  return (
    <div>home</div>
  )
}
```

**Additionally If you use next js latest version (V12)**

import useRouter hook to your component ,

`import { useRouter } from "next/router";` and run the hook inside the component using   `const router = useRouter();`

then you can use  `router.push("/yourpath")` to navigate desired path

Comment: Yes, I am using React Router V6 but I want to call navigate() conditionally.