# Why won't Playwright work when triggering window.location.href in the Firefox project?

Tags: javascript, firefox, playwright, window.location

I have a React component with an onClick listener that looks like this:

```
  <button
    className='h-10 min-h-[2.5rem] m-2 rounded-lg border-2 text-white bg-violet-400 border-white'
    id='logout-cta-button'
    onClick={logout}
  >
    Log Out
  </button>
```

The `logout` function referenced here, is defined in the same file as follows:

```
function logout() {
  fetch('api/logout')
    .then(() => {
      document.cookie = 'token=; expires=Fri, 1 Jan 2000 0:00:00 UTC; path=/';
      window.location.assign('/login');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("Unable to log out for some reason.", err.toString());
    })
}
```

The API shouldn't be relevant here, all you need to know is that it returns 200.

I have a Playwright test that calls for a click on the button as follows:

```
  expect(page.locator('#logout-cta-button')).toBeTruthy();
  await page.locator('#logout-cta-button').click();
  await page.waitForURL('http://localhost:3000/login');
```

This Playwright test passes for Chromium and Webkit. But in Firefox, the redirect call in the `logout` function seems to be ignored resulting in the test failing.  What might I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `/` to the end of the URL in your `waitForURL` call. From the docs for [`waitForURL`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url-option-url):

> Note that if the parameter is a string without wildcard characters, the method will wait for navigation to URL that is exactly equal to the string.

Here's a minimal, reproducible example without React, which is probably incidental to the problem (although if you're using React Router, the [typical redirect is not using `window`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40380010/6243352)). I'm using Chromium, so it doesn't exactly match your situation exactly, but may still resolve it.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="window.location.assign('/login')">go</button>
</body>
</html>
```

login/index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>login</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

pw.test.js:

```js
import {test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.38.0

test("redirects to login", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("http://localhost:3000", {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.locator("button").click();
  await page.waitForURL("http://localhost:3000/login");
});
```

Start a web server: `python -m http.server 3000`, then navigate in your browser to http://localhost:3000 and click the button to make sure the redirect works as expected.

Run the test and observe the failure:

```
$ npx playwright test --headed

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✘  1 pw.test.js:4:5 › redirects to login (30.0s)


  1) pw.test.js:4:5 › redirects to login ───────────────────────────────────────

    Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.

    Error: page.waitForURL: Navigation failed because page was closed!
    =========================== logs ===========================
    waiting for navigation to "http://localhost:3000/login" until "load"
    ============================================================

      5 |   await page.goto("http://localhost:3000");
      6 |   await page.locator("button").click();
    > 7 |   await page.waitForURL("http://localhost:3000/login");
        |              ^
      8 | });
      9 |

        at pw.test.js:7:14

  Slow test file: pw.test.js (30.0s)
  Consider splitting slow test files to speed up parallel execution
  1 failed
    pw.test.js:4:5 › redirects to login ────────────────────────────────────────
```

Next, change the line

```js
await page.waitForURL("http://localhost:3000/login");
```

to

```js
await page.waitForURL("http://localhost:3000/login/"); // trailing slash added
```

Run the test again and observe success:

```
$ npx playwright test

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✓  1 pw.test.js:4:5 › redirects to login (289ms)

  1 passed (838ms)
```

Having shown the probable issue and fix, perhaps a better cross-browser approach is to use a regex:

```js
await page.waitForURL(/\/login\/?$/);
```