# How to fix, cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')

```
import styles from "./dashboard.module.css"
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import SettingsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Settings';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import HistoryIcon from '@mui/icons-material/History';
import LogoutIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Logout';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const drawerWidth = 240;


const handleLogout = () => {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('restToken');
    // Reload the page
    try {
        window.location.reload(true);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

// Attach a confirmation message when the user tries to leave the page

function RestaurantDash(props) {
    const { window } = props;
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
        setMobileOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
    };
    // const dispatch = useDispatch();
    // const token = sessionStorage.getItem('authToken');

    const drawer = (
        <Box onClick={handleDrawerToggle} className={styles.drawerContainer} sx={{ height: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <p className={styles.admin}>Restaurant Controls</p>
            <Button key='drawer1' sx={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '10px', height: '50px' }} color="secondary" startIcon={<SettingsIcon />} onClick={() => setSearchParams({ res: 'products' })}>
                Products
            </Button>
            <Button key='drawer2' sx={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '10px', height: '50px' }} color="secondary" startIcon={<HistoryIcon />} onClick={() => setSearchParams({ res: 'orders' })}>
                Orders
            </Button>
            <Button key='drawer3' sx={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '10px', height: '50px' }} color="secondary" startIcon={<LogoutIcon />} onClick={() => handleLogout()} >
                Logout
            </Button>
        </Box>
    );

    const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

    // async function getDetails() {
    //     const res = await fetch('http://192.168.18.139:3001/admin/admin-dashboard', {
    //         method: 'GET',
    //         headers: {
    //             'Authorization': token,
    //             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    //         }
    //     });
    //     const data = await res.json();
    //     console.log(data);
    // }

    return (
        <div className={styles.dashboardContainer}>
            <div className={styles.heading}>
                <h1 onClick={() => navigate('/')}>
                    Foody.io
                </h1>
                <div>
                    Eat That Foody.
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className={styles.btnContainer}>
                <Toolbar sx={{ width: '10' }}>
                    <IconButton
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="open drawer"
                        edge="start"
                        onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
                        sx={{ display: { md: 'none' } }}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'none', md: 'block' }, width: '1' }}>
                        <p className={styles.admin}>Restaurant Controls</p>

                        <Button key='drawer1' sx={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '10px', height: '50px' }} color="secondary" startIcon={<SettingsIcon />} onClick={() => setSearchParams({ res: 'products' })}>
                            Products
                        </Button>
                        <Button key='drawer2' sx={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '10px', height: '50px' }} color="secondary" startIcon={<HistoryIcon />} onClick={() => setSearchParams({ res: 'orders' })}>
                            Orders
                        </Button>
                        <Button key='drawer3' sx={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '10px', height: '50px' }} color="secondary" startIcon={<LogoutIcon />} onClick={() => handleLogout()} >
                            Logout
                        </Button>
                    </Box>
                </Toolbar>
                <Drawer
                    container={container}
                    variant="temporary"
                    open={mobileOpen}
                    key="right"
                    anchor="right"
                    onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
                    ModalProps={{
                        keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
                    }}
                    sx={{
                        display: { sm: 'block', md: 'none' },
                        '& .MuiDrawer-paper': { boxSizing: 'border-box', width: drawerWidth },
                    }}
                >
                    {drawer}
                </Drawer>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}

export default RestaurantDash
```

The above code is from the component **RestaurantDash**. My project is basically of food ordering system where if a user/admin logs in then 'authToken' is stored in sessionStorage and if restaurant owners logs in then its token is stored in 'restToken' sessionStorage.

To achieve the logout functionality, i just remove the respect item from the sessionStorage and reload the page.

This functionality is working perfectly on home page, where im using Material UI's avatar badge in the navbar. When you click on the badge a dropdown appears with logout option and once you click on it the item is removed and page reloads.

However similar functions on my different page - different route /users/dashboard and /restaurant/dashboard is giving error mentioned above.

```
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route index element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="register" element={sessionStorage.getItem('authToken') !== null ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Register />} />
                <Route path="login" element={sessionStorage.getItem('authToken') !== null ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />} />
                <Route path="users/dashboard" element={sessionStorage.getItem('authToken') !== null ? <UserManagement /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />
                <Route path="restaurant/dashboard" element={sessionStorage.getItem('restToken') !== null ? <RestaurantManagement /> : <Navigate to="/restaurant/login" />} />
                <Route path="restaurant/login" element={sessionStorage.getItem('restToken') === null ? <RestaurantLogin /> : <Navigate to="/restaurant/dashboard" />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Above is my app.js to give u an idea of the routes and how the sessionStorage is playing its role. Maybe its because of the routes that this error is appearing.

I have tried using the try catch which worked at first, but next day when i opened my website it wouldnt reload when i clicked logout.

Comment: Instead of forcing the page to be reloaded, you should use component state to allow react to determine what parts of the page should be rendered again. Generally in React we don't use `window` or `document` since React provides other ways to solve the same problems that you would with these in Vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: In this case, you can use React Router to redirect to the login view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735580/how-to-do-a-redirect-to-another-route-with-react-router

Comment: When it comes to managing states across sibling components, especially logins, I lag behind. Can you please elaborate on " use component state ", with an example if possible. A sample of the approach you are suggesting would be nice

Comment: In this particular situation, I don't think you need to manage the state directly. Instead, use react-router to do it for you. See the link I gave above.

Comment: When you need to share state across components, you should learn about the `useContext()` hook, but I don't think that really applies here.